# Can Android VideoView be used as a PhoneGap Plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to create a PhoneGap Plugin that uses the Android VideoView to play a full screen video without the video controls. But it doesn't seem to work. Calling the plugin function is not doing anything. Am I doing something wrong? or Is this even possible?

```
package com.phonegap.plugins.video;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.net.Uri;

import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;

import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoPlayer extends Plugin {

    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {

        final Plugin that = this;
        final String id = callbackId;

        super.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            //@Override
            public void run() {
                    VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                    //setContentView(videoHolder);
                    videoHolder.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Android/data/MyApp/v2.mp4"));
                    videoHolder.requestFocus();
                    videoHolder.start();
                    that.success(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK), id);
            }
        });

        PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
        result.setKeepCallback(true);
        return result;
    }
}
```

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
function VideoPlayer() {
};


VideoPlayer.prototype.play = function(url) {
    cordova.exec(null, null, "VideoPlayer", "playVideo", [url]);
};


if(!window.plugins) {
    window.plugins = {};
}
if (!window.plugins.videoPlayer) {
    window.plugins.videoPlayer = new VideoPlayer();
}
```

I'm calling the function like below:

```
<a href='#' onclick='javascript:window.plugins.videoPlayer.play("file:///sdcard/Android/data/MyApp/v2.mp4");'>Bismillah</a>
```

Comment: I would like to help out on this plugin. Do you have a github or atlassian or bitbucket project set up? Best, SisaCodes

Comment: have you managed to fix this? I have same requirement, pls advise how you did it?

Comment: I'd also love to know if you've managed this eventually.

Comment: Be aware that the documentation says the execute function has to return a boolean.. Don't know if it really matters, but it could be it isn't overriding the correct function this way.. As @Override needs an exact super function to overwrite

Answer (score 1):

Check this plugin https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer
It works for me and also have easy configuration to integrate in project